# JavaScript date validation

Tags: javascript, datetime, validation

I have a date control which has a dropdown for each date, month and year.

The issue is, I can select 31st Nov. 2015 as well, and when I create date object, I get 1st Dec. 2015.

#### Example

```js
var _date = 31; // value fetched from dropdown
var _month = 10; 
var _year = 2015; 

var date = new Date(_year, _month, _date);
document.write(date)
```

I want to validate this condition, and my current approach is to match `date.getDate()` with `_date` and show an error message if they are different.

Is there a better way to implement this?

#### Code

```js
var _monthList = [
    {id:"1",name:"January"} ,
    {id:"2",name:"February"} ,
    {id:"3",name:"March"} ,
    {id:"4",name:"April"} ,
    {id:"5",name:"May"} ,
    {id:"6",name:"June"},
    {id:"7",name:"July"} ,
    {id:"8",name:"August"} ,
    {id:"9",name:"September"} ,
    {id:"10",name:"October"} ,
    {id:"11",name:"November"} ,
    {id:"12",name:"December"}];


function createYears(){
 var _year = [];
    for (var i = 2000; i<=new Date().getFullYear(); i++){
     _year.push({id:i, name:i});
    }
    $("#cbYear").html(createOptions(_year));
}

function createMonths(){
 $("#cbMonth").html(createOptions(_monthList));
}

function createDates(){
 var _dates = [];
    for (var i=1; i<=31; i++){
     _dates.push({id:i, name:i});
    }
    $("#cbDate").html(createOptions(_dates));
}

function createOptions(dataset){
 var optionStr = "<option></option>";
    $.each(dataset, function(key, value){
        var id = value.id? value.id:key;
        var text = value.name;
        var val = value.value?value.value:value.id;
        optionStr += "<option id="+ id + " name='"+ text+ "' value='"+ val + "'>"+ text + "</option>"
    });
    return optionStr;
}

function registerEvents(){
 $("select").on("change", function(e){
     validateDate();
    });
}

function validateDate(){
 var _date = $("#cbDate option:selected").val();
    var _month = $("#cbMonth option:selected").val();
    var _year = $("#cbYear option:selected").val();
    if(_year && _month && _date){
        var dateObj = new Date(_year, _month-1, _date);
        if(_date != dateObj.getDate()){
            $("#lblError").text("Please Select a valid date");
        }
        else{
         $("#lblError").text("");
        }
    }
}
    
(function(){
 createYears();
    createMonths();
    createDates();
    registerEvents();
})()
```

```css
select{
    background:#fff;
    color:blue;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.error{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cbYear"></select>
<select id="cbMonth"></select>
<select id="cbDate"></select>
<br />
<span id="lblError" class="error"></span>
```

#### Use Case

Select: Invalid Date (e.g. 31st Nov.)

I have also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/817Ladnn/1/) for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you're using for validating a date looks fine to me.

The code is not bad, but here are a few suggestions for improvement:

### IIFE

All of the defined variables and functions leak into global scope. Put them all inside the IIFE to avoid the scope leak: (Note the trailing semicolon)

```
(function(){
    var _monthList = ...
    function createYears() {
        ...
    }

    ...

    createYears();
    createMonths();
    createDates();
    registerEvents();
})();
```

And it's better to execute this function only when the [document is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), so it works regardless of when the script is loaded:

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

### Naming

- Don't prefix your variable names with an underscore. This convention is only used for private properties of objects, which you don't have in your code.
- Use `day` instead of `date` when you mean the day of the month (e.g. `createDays`, `days`, `#cbDay`, `day`), Javascript's `Date#getDate` method is poorly named. Then you can rename `dateObj` to `date`.
- Don't prefix your elements' IDs with `cb` (they're not callbacks). Simply use `year`, `month` and `day` (element IDs don't clash with variable/function names, so they don't need to be prefixed).
- `lblError` -> `errorLabel`. No need to abbreviate.
- `dataset` -> `options`, to be more descriptive.

### Make each function do one thing

`createYears` both generates the year array and manipulates the DOM. Generate the array outside the function instead: (like you did for `createMonths`)

```
var yearList = (function() {
    var years = [];
    for (var i = 2000; i<=new Date().getFullYear(); i++){
        years.push({id:i, name:i});
    }
    return years;
})();
```

Do the same for `createDays`.

`validateDate` both checks if the date is valid and updates `#errorLabel` accordingly. Use a seperate function for testing if a date is valid:

```
function isDateValid(day, month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
    return day == date.getDate();
}
```

### `createOptions`

Every time `createOptions` is called, the return value is set as the HTML value of an element. It's better to pass the element to `createOptions` as an argument and let it manipulate the element to eliminate this repetition.

Each option passed to this function is known to have `id` and `name` properties, so you don't need to check which properties are present.

You don't need to set the IDs for the options, it's enough to set the values. This means the `id` property of the options in the array argument should be renamed to `value` (Change `id` to `value` when generating the arrays).

Finally, you can use jQuery for creating the elements:

```
function createOptions(select, options) {
    options.forEach(function (option) {
        select.append($('<option>', { text: option.name, value: option.value }));
    });
}
```

Now `createYears` looks like this:

```
function createYears() {
    createOptions($('#year'), yearList);
}
```

Which is so short that there is no need to make `createYears`, `createMonths` and `createDays` multiple functions.

### Seperating logic from DOM

Put all the functions that are responsible for the logic first, and after them put code that accesses the page's DOM: (i.e. code that has strings with specific element IDs)

```
var dayList = ...;
var monthList = ...;
var yearList = ...;

function createOptions(select, options){
    ...
}

function isDateValid(day, month, year) {
    ...
}

createOptions($('#year'), yearList);
createOptions($('#month'), monthList);
createOptions($('#day'), dayList);

$("select").on("change", function validateDate() {
    var day = $("#day").val(); /* NOTE: No need to use additional selectors when you're already selecting by ID */
    var month = $("#month").val();
    var year = $("#year").val();
    if(year && month && day) {
        /* NOTE: I used a ternary expression to shorten the code */
        $("#errorLabel").text(isDateValid(day, month, year) ? "" : "Please select a valid date");
    }
});
```

This makes the code easier to understand and more reusable (e.g. it will make having multiple date forms on the same page easier).

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Will incorporate it in my code. Also I used `cb` in html as a prefix for *combobox*. Is it bad to use such prefix? Like 'lbl' for label, 'txt' for text etc.

Comment: @Rajesh `cb` isn't often use to mean combobox, so it'll probably not be understood by someone who reads the code (e.g. me :-)). It's sometime used to mean `callback`, although that's not very common either. It's best to avoid abbreviations, except very common ones (e.g. `num` for `number`).  But as I said there's no need to prefix the element IDs. Instead, you may want to use the more descriptive selector `$('select#year')` in your code so it's obvious it's a `<select>` element.